# What is a "DateTime?" as opposed to just a DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, nullable

What is the difference between a `DateTime?` and a `DateTime` (without a question mark) in C#?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`DateTime?` can be null as opposed to `DateTime`

Comment: i.e. Nullable<DateTime> - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Actually, `DateTime?` itself is not null as it is a value type as well.  `Nullable<T>` exposes a `HasValue` property that the compiler uses to "fake" reference type semantics on a value type that is wrapped in `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 19):

A question mark after a value type is a shorthand notation for the [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) structure.

> Represents an object whose underlying
>   type is a value type that can also be
>   assigned null like a reference type.

The `Nullable<T>` structure allows you to wrap value types (like `DateTime`, `Int32`, `Guid`, etc.) and treat them like reference types in certain respects.  It does get a bit more complicated (in terms of assignment, lifted operators, and other things) and as such I would recommend that you read [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx) and its related articles.

> Nullable types are instances of the
>   `System.Nullable` struct. A nullable
>   type can represent the normal range of
>   values for its underlying value type,
>   plus an additional null value. For
>   example, a `Nullable<Int32>`, pronounced
>   "Nullable of Int32," can be assigned
>   any value from -2147483648 to
>   2147483647, or it can be assigned the
>   null value. A `Nullable<bool>` can be
>   assigned the values true or false, or
>   null. The ability to assign null to
>   numeric and Boolean types is
>   particularly useful when dealing with
>   databases and other data types
>   containing elements that may not be
>   assigned a value. For example, a
>   Boolean field in a database can store
>   the values true or false, or it may be
>   undefined.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime? is another way of writing Nullable<DateTime>.  I suggest you read this to learn more about nullable:

[Nullable(T) Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)